# Remove MS Word auto-format characters in c# / oracle12

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, oracle12c

When content is copy+pasted from Word into an input text box and then saved to a VARCHAR2 field some of the auto-formatted characters from Word are transformed into special characters,

eg. two hypens (--) auto-format to a dash (—), and when this dash is saved to the database it is transformed into an upside down question mark (¿)

Is there a way in c# to undo this? Or is there an oracle datatype better suited than VARCHAR2?

I've tried using char.IsControl() in c# but it's doesn't appear to catch these characters

Comment: Your text should be fine once its been read back out of the database in the correct encoding.  Your database's character set is configured to the wrong one.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'll need to go speak to the DBAs!